# read a specific line from a file

Tags: c#, asp.net, readline

I am trying to get a list of lines that are before lines that contains a specific word.  Here is my script:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int counter = 0;
    string line;

    System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("E:\\overview2.srt");
    List<string> lines = new List<string>();
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains("medication"))
        {


            int x = counter - 1;
            Console.WriteLine(x); // this will write the line number not its contents

        }

        counter++;
    }

    file.Close();
}
```

Comment: How many lines are you going to want to keep once the word is found

Comment: Looks like a homework question where the hint is that the list of lines has been declared but not used, so you just need to work out how to add something to the list and then reference earlier occurrences.

Comment: if line contains seek to end of file and exit loop, else write line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will show all lines immediately before any line that contains your search text.

```
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string cacheline = "";
        string line;

        System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\overview2.srt");
        List<string> lines = new List<string>();
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("medication"))
            {
                lines.Add(cacheline);
            }
            cacheline = line;
        }
        file.Close();

        foreach (var l in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(l);           
        }
    }
```

It's difficult to tell from your question where you're looking for ALL lines before the found line or just a single line. (You would have to deal with the special case where the search text is found on the first line).

Comment: I need to write a list of all lines contents (text) not the line number.  For example if line number 6 includes the word "medication", I need to get the text of line 5.  Thanks

Comment: This code should do exactly that. The previous line is cached on each loop through. It can then be saved to the List if 'medication' is found in the next line.

Comment: It worked well, except it displayed one line only, there are 15 lines that contains the specified word "medication". thanks

Comment: I tested it before posting. Can you confirm that 'medication' is being found in the 'Contains()'?

Comment: You are right, I had a break point to see the Console window.  Thank you so much.  Now I need to figure out how to the list of lines as an Array.

Comment: lines.ToArray() will convert the list to an array. Did I understand?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21892/discussion-between-user373721-and-nick-pearce)

Answer (score 2):

Using LINQ method syntax:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines("E:\\overview2.srt")
        .Where(line => line.Contains("medication"))
        .ToList();
```

and LINQ keyword syntax:

```
var lines = (
    from line in File.ReadLines("E:\\overview2.srt")
    where line.Contains("medication")
    select line
).ToList();
```

If you need an array, use `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()`.

Also, if all you need is to iterate once over the lines, don't bother with `ToArray` or `ToList`:

```
var query = 
    from line in File.ReadLines("E:\\overview2.srt")
    where line.Contains("medication")
    select line;
foreach (var line in query) {
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `Queue<string>`.  Add each line to it as you pass over it.  If it has more than the required number of lines in it dequeue the first item.  When you hit your required search expression the `Queue<string>` contains all the lines you will need to output.

Or if memory is no object, you could just use `File.ReadAllLines` (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines.aspx) and index away into an array.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 int linenum = 0;
                foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines("Your Address"))
                {
                    if (line.Contains("medication"))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("line Number:{} Text:{}"linenum,line)
//Add to your list or ...
                    }
                    linenum++;
                }
```